# Is it possible to make a substitution command that preserves the case of the matched pattern?

Tags: substitute

Consider the following constant definition:

```
define("_TBL_USERS","users");
```

Now, I want to transform it into:

```
define("_TBL_USER_ITEMS","user_items");
```

I tried the command:

```
s/\(user\)s\?/\1_items/gi
```

And the result is:

```
define("_TBL_USER_items","user_items");
```

Is there a way to use a substitute command that will modify the case depending on the matched pattern, so the first `items` is substituted in uppercase?

Answer (score 4):

There is plugin for this - [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) by Tim Pope. No configuration required.

For your example do one of these commands (does not matter which):

```
:Subvert;USERS;USER_ITEMS;g

:Subvert;users;user_items;g
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with one substitution command but it's a bit hairy and you might want to just use two substitutions. For instance here's a two substitution version that has a bit of a shortcut in it...

```
:s/\(user\)s\?/\1_items/gI | s/\(USER\)S\?/\U~/g
```

The `~` in the replacement part of the second command copies the replacement of the last executed substitution (in our case from the LHS of the `|`). By prepending that with `\U` we force `\1_items` to uppercase.

If you want to know the single substitution version...better take a seat. ;)

```
:s/\(user\)s\?/\=submatch(1) . (submatch(1) ==# 'user' ? '_items' : '_ITEMS')/gi
```

This is using what's known as a [*sub-replace* expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression). I've answered a couple question recently using this technique: [How to run a substitute command on only a certain part of the line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20704/how-to-run-a-substitute-command-on-only-a-certain-part-of-the-line/20706#20706) and [How to create regex group with dependency with earlier group via math operations](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-to-create-regex-group-with-dependency-with-earlier-group-via-math-operations/26301#26301)

The key is the `\=` that begins the substitution. It means "everything after this point is to be evaluated as a VimL expression and the result of that evaluation becomes the replacement string". [`submatch(1)`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#submatch()) is equivalent to `\1` and we're appending to that a string that is conditional on the *value* of `submatch(1)`. Specifically, the part between the parens says, *If the submatch is case sensitively equal to 'user' then append to the submatch "_items" otherwise append "_ITEMS".*
"

The two-substitution version is easier to understand and less typing so that's what I would use. If you really want to avoid typing a pattern more than once then, hmmm, you could use this, I suppose...

```
:let c='s/\(USER\)S\?/\1_ITEMS/I' | exe c | exe tolower(c).'I'
```

Alternatively, run the first substitution then run a second command...

```
:s/\(USER\)S\?/\1_ITEMS/I
:exe tolower(@:).'I'
```

Both of these do two substitutions but at least you only have to type one of them. **;)**

*(Just in case there's confusion, I don't actually recommend using either of the last two...they're a bit too hacky. But, hey, if you want to do so anyways then go for it. :)*